# Are there any programming languages for Ubuntu Server with a web interface for their IDE?

Tags: webserver, interface

I have Ubuntu  22.04 installed with WebMin and Cockpit as useful web interfaces. This allows me to SSH into this server either directly through SSH or through the web interface of either web application. Which makes it very useful to manage these systems without too much trouble. Especially since this server is inside a closet with no keyboard, mouse or monitor. This server is used as a web server for projects I'm working on and. I also use it for educational purposes, even though I'm pretty skilled already.
But while most of my development happens on my Windows desktop before deploying it to this server (or elsewhere) I would like to write code directly on this server sometimes. So it would be useful if I have any web-based IDE that I can install on this server and then basically start writing code. The programming languages it support aren't that important as I've been developing ever since Minix was hip (decades) and I've seen most of them already. I am just looking for an web-based IDE to install and use it for creating small tasks for this server.
For now, SSH does the job with C, so that's okay. But I'm looking for other options.

Comment: For writing python code, [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) works well. The default config allows access only from `127.0.0.1` but you can [change it](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/remote-jupyter-notebook/).

Comment: For general programming, there is both [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [OpenVSCode](https://www.gitpod.io/blog/openvscode-server-launch).

Comment: @ArturMeinild But VSCode has no web interface, does it? There's a web version of VSCode, but that's hosted by Microsoft. I need one hosted on this server.

Comment: I'm thinking something like this: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server *"Code-server is VS Code running on a remote server, accessible through the browser."*

Comment: Alternate suggestion: if you install VS Code on Windows, and install the `Remote - SSH` extension, you'll be able to have the VS Code editor running on Windows, but you can tell it to connect over SSH to the server so that you'll be able to edit folders/projects/files on the server, and you'll get a shell, but the IDE itself is on Windows. Not exactly what you asked for, but it might work

Comment: @cocomac I cannot install VSCode as this is the server version of Ubuntu. All I have is SSH as terminal. I have *NO physical access to this server*. And I don't want to run VSCode on another computer, but code through a web interface. I need an option to write a simple application from anywhere by logging into the web interface of this server and then start coding.